# sscanf make ignore all symbols including newline

Tags: c++, string, parsing, scanf

I have a string, that contains data from file, here example

```
string str = "File:./img/Char2.png\r\n
Size:128x128\r\n
Frames:2\r\n
Hand:79x54\r\n
Horizontal_Animated:0"
```

And using this string I hope initialize variables, but hit one ploblem:
I wanted use `sscanf(str.c_str(),"%*s Size:%dx%d",&Width,&Height)`
to parse this string and it works, but there is one thing that I don't like:
for second, third.... calls of `sscanf` I need add one more `%*s` because this thing doesn't ignore `\r\n`, so next code looks like this:

```
sscanf(contents.c_str(),"%*s %*s Frames:%d",&MaxFrames);
sscanf(contents.c_str(),"%*s %*s %*s Hand:%dx%d",&HandX,&HandY)
```

So, how do i need change format string for right parsing without tonns of `%*s`?

ps. I know about regular expressions in C++11, but I'm curious about solutions

Comment: *So, how do i need change format string for right parsing without tonns of %*s?* Simple: Don't use `sscanf`. C++11 has regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

As the data is already in a `std::string`, I would first use as `std::stringstream` and `std::getline` to split the whole string in lines. Once it is done, `sscanf` is enough to parse the individual lines.

The C stdlib way to to the splitting would be to use `strtok`. But as it modifies the string, you cannot directly use it on `std.c_str()`. You have to first make a modifiable copy with `strdup`.

But of course, regexes could be considered here.